# Optimize the query "Select * from tableA"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I was asked in an interview to enlighten the ways one can use to optimize the query `Select * from TableA` if it is taking a lot of time to execute. (TableA) can be any table with large amount of data. The interviewer didn't leave me any option like to select few columns or to use "WHERE" clause rather he wanted me to give solution for the subject query.

Comment: Have you thought about what the interviewer said at all?

Comment: Indexes, filters and keys oh my!

Comment: At some point I thought may be he is scoffing at me, I couldn't draw any solution and that's why I am here.

Comment: Normalization, keys, partitions...

Comment: It's really hard to know what he is looking for. He might be relatively inexperienced and expected answers like "list all the columns instead of * since that's way faster" or "add an ORDER BY because that will always speed it up." The kinds of things an experienced person might be looking for are: inspect the query plan, see if there are computed columns or other similar things taking additional resources; revisit the requirements - do the users really need the whole table in arbitrary order?; is there a clustered index on the table; if not, is it full of forwarding pointers?

Comment: This seems like a poor, really open ended question because there are so many off the wall answers that completely depend on the actual circumstances which you don't know; answers like add memory to the server to increase caching, install faster network cards, use paged queries (skip/take) since it's user-perceived slowness, etc., etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's really hard to know what the interviewer was looking for.

They might be relatively inexperienced and expected answers like:

- "list all the columns instead of * since that's way faster!"; or,
- "add an ORDER BY because that will always speed it up!"

The kinds of things an experienced person might be looking for are:

- inspect the query plan, are there computed columns or other similar things taking additional resources?
- revisit the requirements - do the users really need the whole table in arbitrary order?
- is there a clustered index on the table; if not, is the heap full of forwarding pointers?
- is there excessive fragmentation on the underlying table (and/or the index being used to satisfy the query)?
- is the query being blocked?
- what is the query waiting on?
- is the query waiting on an external resource (e.g. crappy I/O subsystem, a memory grant, a tempdb autogrow)?
- is the query parallel and suffering packet waits because the stats are out of date?

There are a lot of underlying things that may be making that query slow *or* that may make that query a bad choice.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, you have provided a greater insight regarding the question. Question dint seem inappropriate as there are underlying mechanisms, as you have highlighted, which can make this query run slow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually some databases will have optimize commands that will rebuild the database tables to reduce fragmentation - and this way actually improve the performance for such queries.

PostgreSQL and SQLite have the command

```
VACUUM;
```

MySQL and ORACLE have a command

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table;
```

It is expensive, as it will move around a lot of data. But in doing so, it will make the pages more balanced and this way usually shrink the total database size (some databases may however decide to add an index at this point, so it may also grow).

Since the data is stored in pages, reducing the number of pages by rebuilding the database *can* improve the performance even for a `SELECT * FROM table;` statement.